# dealing with nested quotes in html generated from c#

Tags: c#, html, formatting, quotes

i am using a 3rd party library to show tooltips, like so:

```
string tooltip = "test";
output.Write("onmouseover='Tip(\"" + test + "\");'");  // work fine :)
```

i'm having problem with situations like the following where i need quotes for formatting:

```
string tooltip = "<span style='color:red;'>test</span>";
output.Write("onmouseover='Tip(\"" + test + "\");'");  // no working :(
```

how can i escape the quotes needed for the html in the tooltip so it doesn't break the function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace any instance of `"` with `&quot;` as follows:

```
test.Replace( "\"", "&quot;" )
```

Comment: That still leaves it open for XSS attacks.

Comment: I think you're incorrectly assuming that the string test is somehow coming in from the end user, which is not something that I see from the sample above. To me it's very clear that he controls the tooltips.

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect use for the Microsoft [Anti-Xss Library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09&displaylang=en)

With it, you call the JavaScriptEncode function, which will build a string like this:

```
Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode("ab'c\"d")
// 'ab\x27c\x22d'
```

Notice that **it includes the quotes**.

You would take that, HTML encode it, and plop it directly into your parenthesis.

Something like this:

```
string tooltip = "<span style='color:red;'>test</span>";
output.Write("onmouseover=\"Tip(" + AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(test) + ");\"");  // working :)
```