# Passing string value to javascript from c#.net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

Basically I have a string variable and i pass this string variable to javascript function using the code below.

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[counter].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"showAlert("+tempString+",event);\"";
```

my javascript function is as follows:

```
function showAlert(stringVal,ex) {
       //var temp = document.getElementById("HTxtFieldPopIp").value;
      // temp = "testing";
      // alert(temp);
        alert(stringVal);
   }
```

But this doesnt give me a alert box.

When i remove the parameter and run the commented pieces of code the same happens. Any suggestions.

Comment: Does this function gets fired? If so,try adding return false inside function showAlert;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223543/dealing-with-nested-quotes-in-html-generated-from-c-sharp

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net or MVC as front end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the string:

```
"onmouseover=\"showAlert("+tempString+",event);\""
```

becomes:

```
"onmouseover=\"showAlert('"+tempString+"',event);\""
```

So, if tempString equals foo then the js dynamically generated would be:

```
onmouseover="showAlert('foo',event);"
```

Comment: +0. While correct, using properly encoded string would be much safer - current sample is likely cause XSS ([old MSDN article on XSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) and method that should be used now to construct the inner portion of string [JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992817.aspx).

Comment: He's just doing a silly alert on a tempString.  I was answering why it wasn't working :)

Comment: +1. Probably you are right, I should not expect people to care about it :).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need quotes around tempString. Your C# code now results in:

```
onmouseover="showAlert(testing,event)"
```

Change it to

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[counter].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"showAlert('"+tempString+"',event);\"";
```